# How to split the character variable to multiple variable in SAS?

Tags: sas

I want to split the below character variable (Have) to multiple variable (Time, Lane and Direction).

```
data outdata;
input have & $20.;
datalines;
00:00 Lane 1 (North)
Lane 2 (North)
Lane 3 (South)
Lane 4 (East)
All Lanes
01:00 Lane 1 (North)
;
run;
```

[image]

I got all variables except the Lane variable.

```
data up; 
set outdata; 
Hour=scan(Have, 1); 
Hour=compress(hour,'','a'); 
Lane = scan(Have, 2); 
Direction =scan(Have, -1); 
Direction = tranwrd(Direction, "Lanes", " "); 
run;
```

Comment: Are these two questions related? It's better if you separate them if they are not? If they are, it may be easier but you need to identify how they're related.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to import data from a badly formatted Excel file? Or are the fields always in the specific locations?

Comment: Exactly :( You can skip the second question may be....can u help me how to get the first question...i have done for other columns except the lane one?

Comment: How to extract the Lane variable from the Have variable?

Comment: If you've done the other column it's easy to use TRANWRD to remove the other components. Show what you've done and I'll show how to implement the TRANWRD function.

Comment: data upwork;
 set outdata;
 Hour=scan(Have, 1);
 Hour=compress(hour,'','a');
 Lane = scan(Have, 2);
 Direction =scan(Have, -1);
 Direction = tranwrd(Direction, "Lanes", " "); run;

Comment: Please add your code by editing your question, not in the comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224563/discussion-between-learner-and-reeza).

Comment: Can you please post the data as text, I don't want to type it out.

Comment: data outdata;
input have & $20.;
datalines;
00:00 Lane 1 (North)
Lane 2 (North)
Lane 3 (South)
Lane 4 (East)
All Lanes
01:00 Lane 1 (North)
;
run;

Comment: Hi, edited the question with codes...please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that works on your example data.

Use SCAN() where possible and then use TRANWRD to 'remove' the found words, leaving you only with the Lane information at the end. This works on your sample data but may not generalize depending on how variable your data formats are in the actual data. If you encounter edge cases, please update your sample data to reflect these cases.

```
data up;
    set outdata;
    Direction=scan(Have, 2, "()");

    if anydigit(char(have, 1)) then
        do;
            hour=scan(have, 1);
        end;
    *Remove direction;
    have2=tranwrd(have, catt("(", Direction, ")"), "");
    *Remove time;
    Lane=compbl(tranwrd(have2, trim(hour), ""));
    keep Have Direction Hour Lane;
run;

proc print data=up;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditionally held `input` (`@`) to read and retain the `time` value.  Other `input` statement features such as an adjusted list of delimiter characters (`dlm=`) is needed to read the `lane` and `direction` values.

Example:

```
data outdata;
  attrib 
    time format=time5.
    lane length=$10
    direction length=$5
  ;

  retain time;

  input @;
  if index(_infile_,':') then input time time5. @;

  input lane direction;

  infile datalines dlm='()' missover;
datalines;
00:00 Lane 1 (North)
Lane 2 (North)
Lane 3 (South)
Lane 4 (East)
All Lanes
01:00 Lane 1 (North)
;
```

[image]